# R read.dta and unz not working

Tags: r, unzip, read.csv

I read a lot of files into R from zipped sources. I try to use the R function `unz` to read from zipped files because unlike unzip it does not leave any unzipped files on my harddisk.

However, this does not seem to work for zipped `*.dta` (Stata) files:

```
library(foreign)

temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/WDI_csv.zip", temp)
wdi_unz <- read.csv(unz(temp, "WDI_Data.csv"))
unlink(temp)

temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://www.rug.nl/research/ggdc/data/pwt/v80/pwt80.zip",temp)
pwt_unzip <- read.dta(unzip(temp, "pwt80.dta"))
pwt_unz   <- read.dta(unz(temp, "pwt80.dta"))
unlink(temp)
```

Sorry for using the rather large World Development Indicators database (its 40+ MB), but I did not find any better working example.

The code produces an error when reading `pwt_unz`, [edit: but not when reading `pwt_unzip`]. What is the problem there? Probably it has something to do with the return value of `unz` not being compatible with the input for read.dta?

Comment: Unz only works in binary mode.  Is the dta file binary?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need read.dta

Have a look here :

**http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.dta.html**

Comment: Yes, that is what I am using as a wrapper around unz or unzip, respectively.

Comment: Do you know which type of compression the dta is wrapped around?  Is it standard zip?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know that. All the files I tried so far are from the same source (Groningen growth and Development Center), so indeed it could be that this is a problem specific for their zipped dta's. To check, I tried anotther one [link](http://nces.ed.gov/surveys/ssocs/data/zip/ssocs06_stata.zip), but ran into the same problem. Are there different kinds of zip compressions? If so, how can I find out which one is present in the file at hand?